# Weird OutOfMemoryError with android bitmaps: Why does showing and then hiding the containing View avoid it?

Tags: android, camera, out-of-memory

I was a frequent guest at stackoverflow until I ran into a problem that I really couldn't find anything existing about. So here is my first question:

I am building a camera app in which the user can take several pictures before proceeding to the next step. I want to give the user the possibility to review and delete pictures while stying in the camera stage, so I have written a custom View to show Thumbnails of the already captured images with a delete button. These "Thumbviews" are contained in a LinearLayout that is located on top of the camerapreview-SurfaceView and has a default visibility of "GONE". The user can toggle the visibility with a button.

It all works fine, but I have one problem:
When I take more than about 10 pictures, I get an OutOfMemoryError. The thumbnails are really small and don't take a lot of memory and also I recycle the original Bitmaps and perform a System.gc() after creating the thumbs. 
The weird thing is, when I press the button that sets the visibility of the containing LinearLayout to "VISIBLE" and again to "GONE", apparently all the memory gets freed and I can take many more pictures than 10.
I've tried switching the visibility in code but that doesn't work, and also destroying the drawing cache.
There has to be another way to free that memory besides pushing my visibility button 2 times ;-)

Here's the code for the ThumbView:

```
public class ThumbView extends View {

private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Bitmap mScaledBitmap;
private int mWidth, mHeight, mPosX, mPosY;
static private Bitmap mDeleteBitmap;
private File mPreviewFile;
private File mFinalFile;
private Orientation mOrientation;
private boolean mRed;

public ThumbView(Context context, Bitmap bitmap, File previewFile, File finalFile, Orientation orientation) {
    super(context);
    mBitmap = bitmap;
    mPreviewFile = previewFile;
    mFinalFile = finalFile;
    mOrientation = orientation;
    if(mDeleteBitmap != null)
        return;
    mDeleteBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.deletebutton);
}

public void deleteFile()
{
    if(mPreviewFile != null && mPreviewFile.exists())
    {
        mPreviewFile.delete();
    }
    if(mFinalFile != null && mFinalFile.exists())
    {
        mFinalFile.delete();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    mWidth  = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mWidth);

    if(mBitmap == null)
        return;
    mHeight = mWidth;

    float bitmapRatio = mBitmap.getWidth() / (float) mBitmap.getHeight();

    if(bitmapRatio > 1)
    {
        mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, mWidth,
                (int)(mWidth/bitmapRatio), true);
        mPosY = (mWidth-mScaledBitmap.getHeight())/2;
    }
    else
    {
        mScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, (int)(mHeight*bitmapRatio),
                mHeight, true);
        mPosX = (mHeight-mScaledBitmap.getWidth())/2;
    }


    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.postRotate(-90);

    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mScaledBitmap, 0, 0, mScaledBitmap.getWidth(), mScaledBitmap.getHeight(), mtx, true);
    mScaledBitmap = b;
    b = null;

    mBitmap.recycle();
    mBitmap = null;
    System.gc();
}

public boolean deleteButtonPressed(float x, float y)
{
    Rect r = new Rect(mPosY, mPosX, mPosY+mDeleteBitmap.getWidth(),
            mPosX+mDeleteBitmap.getHeight());
    if(r.contains((int)x, (int)y))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void setRed(boolean red)
{
    mRed = red;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mScaledBitmap, mPosY, mPosX, new Paint());
    canvas.drawBitmap(mDeleteBitmap, mPosY, mPosX, new Paint());
    if(mRed)
        canvas.drawColor(0x55FF0000);
}
```

}

Comment: How small is small? I know a few that consider 512x512 to be that, but that ends up being around 768k in RGB24 (512 pixels * 512 pixels * 3 bytes/pixel). 768k * 10 images = 7.6 megabytes. That would push the Android heap limits

Comment: Question #2: Are you adding these into a view manually, or are you using something like a listview?

Comment: Its less than 200 * 200, and it's a manual nested linearlayout inside a scrollview that results in a two-column grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so stupid. Obviously my onMeasure() won't be called while the View stays GONE and therefore the original bitmap stays in memory. I changed visibility to INVISIBLE and everything works fine now.

Comment: Heh, I was going to suggest something like that :) I would handle the bitmap logic completely outside the view...

Comment: I do it in the onMeasure() method of the view because I need the thumbail to fit perfectly into the view and I don't know the views size before that. I'd give you an upvote, because you kind of made me think about the GONE-visibility one more time, but I don't have enough reputation yet ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The "why does it not break" answer's easy. When the visibility of a child view (or container) is set to GONE, the parent layout will (generally) skip it and not even bother rendering it. It's not "hidden", it's not there at all.

If your thumbnails are really thumbnails you shouldn't be running out of memory, however, I think you're not downsampling them (I could be wrong). How are you showing them? You should share that piece of code. (New Photo -> Thumbnail Image -> Image View)

Comment: I am downsampling them in the onMeasure method, where I also recycle the original (large) bitmap at the end.

The view is GONE by default. If i leave it to GONE, it DOES break. It just doesn't break if I switch to VISIBLE and then back to GONE again.

Comment: The downsampling and garbage collection definitely is along the lines of what you want to do